# Unable to run a command from usr/bin

Tags: 13.04, permissions

Here is what I have

```
$ ls -al /usr/bin/scala
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Aug 30 21:00 /usr/bin/scala -> /opt/scala/scala-2.10.1/bin/scala
```

but

```
$ scala
-bash: /usr/bin/scala: Permission denied
```

how do I fix this?

Comment: I'd guess you probably don't have executable rights on `/opt/scala/scala-2.10.1/bin/scala` or the executable bit is not set on scala.

Comment: What are the permissions for `/opt/scala/scala-2.10.1/bin/scala`?

Comment: @edwin, you're right.

Comment: @Nodebody, you too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file in `/usr/bin` isn't the binary itself, but a symbolic link (symlink) to the "real" binary at `/opt/scala/scala-2.10.1/bin/scala`. In order to execute your command you need to have sufficient permissions on that file, not (only) on the symlink. Otherwise, permissions could be circumvented very easily, just by creating a symlink with less restrictive permissions.

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal and type as

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/scala
```

Then you can run it. the only problem is you have no direct access to root directory file system `/` .